# Admin Dashboard Error

Tags: magento-1.9, error, migration

After migrating am facing some error like as shown below, How to solve those error?

Here the **error on admin page**

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php:555
Stack trace: 
#0 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput() 
#1 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/IndexController.php(82): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout() 
#2 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_IndexController->loginAction() 
#3 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(254): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login') 
#4 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http)) 
#5 /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(365): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch() 
#6 /home/pataak/public_html/app/Mage.php(6 in /home/pataak/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php on line 555
```

and Here the **Front page error**:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 4096 bytes) in /home/pataak/public_html/lib/Less/Parser.php
>   on line 2270

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you are using php7.

1. In your cpanel goto php versions and select 5.x instead of php7.
2. For memory limit exception increase your memory limit from `php.ini`

Comment: Yes, I using php7. Which version( 5.5 or 5.8) is better for magento1?

Comment: Both should work fine

Answer (score 1):

If you are using WHM / cpanel then in WHM cpanel there is an option to do php multiphpini. There you can edit your corresponding version.

Check back at www.yourwebsite/phpinfo.php if the value changed.